# Installation error message with TestLink for Mac

Tags: macos, testlink

I am trying to install Testlink on OS X for Mac.  However, I am getting the following message which will not let me continue with installation. I have seen solutions for other operating systems but not for Mac.  I am inexperienced with Mac.  Any help appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it..

```
chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testlink-1.9.16/gui/templates_c

sudo mkdir /var/testlink/logs/
sudo mkdir /var/testlink/upload_area/
```

Then give the last two directories writeable permissions:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/testlink/logs/
sudo chmod 777 /var/testlink/upload_area/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the `/var/www/html/testlink/gui/templates_c` directory is writable (logged with the user used to run the webserver process).

To resolve this issue try to follow steps:

1. ssh into the machine you are installing
2. move to the testlink main directory, in my case: `cd /var/www/html/testlink/gui`
3. change the permision of templates_c: `sudo chmod a+w templates_c`

Now try to install testlink again.

Comment: Thanks, but I resolved it with the above steps I mentioned.